# PrimeNG Angular 8 p-dropdown selectedItem template not rendering

Tags: typescript, primeng, angular8, primeng-dropdowns, selecteditemtemplate

Below is my markup for the custom template design for the PrimeNG p-dropdown control

```
<p-dropdown [options]="list" [(ngModel)]="selectedListItem" (onChange)="selectionChanged($event)">

    <ng-template let-item pTemplate="selectedItem">
      <div class="custom-template-div">
        <div class="pull-left location-icon {{item.value.cssClass}}"></div>
        <div class="header-line pull-left"><b>{{item.value.text1}}</b></div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <div class="detail-line"><i>{{item.value.text2}}</i></div>
      </div>
    </ng-template>

    <ng-template let-item pTemplate="item">
      <div class="custom-template-div">
        <div class="pull-left location-icon {{item.cssClass}}"></div>
        <div class="header-line pull-left"><b>{{item.text1}}</b></div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <div class="detail-line"><i>{{item.text2}}</i></div>
      </div>
    </ng-template>

  </p-dropdown>
```

In this control the `<ng-template let-item pTemplate="item">` section is working as expected when the dropdown is listing the items with CSS icons, but when an item been selected, it is not showing in the control, but in the code level the items is selected.

I'm using a custom DTO as below;

```
export class ListItemDto {
    text: string;
    text1: string;
    text2: string;
    value: string;
    cssClass: string;
}
```

**I'm having issue only with** the `<ng-template let-item pTemplate="selectedItem">` template where as I have tried `item.value` to get the object as well as directly `item` also. Both are not working for me.

Any information would be helpfull. Thanks!

Comment: </div> --> needs to change to </div>

Comment: @EhsanKiani that was a typo in posting, I updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My colleague found the issue and it is just to have the `label` and `value` properties available in whatever the custom DTO we use as the collection. I only had `value` property.

```
export class ListItemDto {
    text: string;
    text1: string;
    text2: string;

    label: string;
    value: string;

    cssClass: string;
}
```

If the custom DTO contains the properties `label` and `value` properties along with other custom properties, the `selectedItem` template will start to work.

Comment: also another way to workaround this is to set the optionLabel attribute. then you have access to your custom object in the template via item.value.text1

Comment: thank you for this, been bumping my head for a whole day... they really come up with crappy solutions sometimes